# How to write "<" in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

How to write `<` in LaTeX or in `elsarticle` template? Like `(p<0.01)`.

When I put `\` before `<`, LaTeX can't read and just shows `!` in pdflatex
Thnx.

Comment: You do not need a backslash, just `(p<0.01)` or `$(p<0.01)$` if you are outside math mode.

Comment: LaTeX is not HTML you know :)

Comment: Thank you @Schrödinger's cat

Answer (score 4):

- To use the `<` in text mode under pdfLaTeX, you need to run

  ```
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  ```

  in the preamble. The default font encoding, `OT1`, used by pdfLaTeX is not set up to handle `<` -- or, for that matter, `>` and `|` -- properly in text mode.
- You need not do anything special in math mode. E.g., `$1<2$` or `$u|v$` both produce the expected output.

---

Here's a full MWE (minimum working example) that illustrates this issue. The input in *both* screenshots is

```
< > | \quad $2<3$, $4>3$, $u|v$.
```

[image]
[image]

In the upper screenshot, the test document was compiled without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`; in the lower screenshot, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is active. Observe that the symbols `<`, `>`, and `|` are produced correctly in math mode whether or not the `T1` font encoding is specified.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
< > | \quad $2<3$, $4>3$, $u|v$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mico

Answer (score 3):

In the modern toolchain, with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can use Unicode. Load `\usepackage{fontspec}` or `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, and this, as well as many other things, will just work.

In addition to Mico’s suggestions `\textgreater` and `\textless` also work.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `\textless` and `\textgreater`. :-)

Comment: Thank you @ Davislor